# C++ operator overloading prefix/suffix

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I'm learning operator overloading in C++. The original suffix ++ has the property that it has lower precedence than the assignment operator. So for example, `int i=0, j=0; i=j++; cout<<i<<j` will output 01. But this property seems to be lost when I overload the postfix ++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class V
{
public:
    int vec[2];
    V(int a0, int a1)
    {
        vec[0]=a0;vec[1]=a1;
    }
    V operator++(int dummy)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            ++vec[i];
        }
        V v(vec[0],vec[1]);
        return v;
    }
    V operator=(V other)
    {
        vec[0]=other.vec[0];
        vec[1]=other.vec[1];
        return *this;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "(" << vec[0] << ", " << vec[1] << ")" << endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    V v1(0,0), v2(1,1);
    v1.print();

    v1=v2++;
    v1.print();
}
```

outputs (0,0)(2,2) while I expected (0,0)(1,1).

Can you help me understand why it's like this, and any possibility of restoring the original property?

Comment: "The original suffix ++ has the property that it has lower precedence than the assignment operator." Unless you are one of the people who say that lower precedence binds stronger than higher precedence, that is wrong. The precedence of the post-increment is higher than that of assignment, but a post-increment returns the non-incremented value.

Comment: thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding, I tested the issue using int i=0, j=0; i=(j++); cout<<i<<j; and it outputs 01. So it's not about precedence but rather the return mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

It prints `(0,0)(2,2)` because your operator `++`, unlike the built-in one, returns a copy of the `V` object it acts upon *after* incrementing it, rather than before.

This is completely under your control when you overload an operator, so it is your responsibility to make it behave like the corresponding built-in operator in this respect.

This is how you could rewrite your operator to achieve that goal:

```
V operator++(int dummy)
{
    V v(vec[0],vec[1]); // Make a copy before incrementing: we'll return this!
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        ++vec[i];
    }
    return v; // Now this is *not* a copy of the incremented V object,
              // but rather a copy of the V object before incrementing!
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/Gz3oi4).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a copy of `vec[0]` and `vec[1]` before you increment them, not after. That way `return v` will return the original values rather than the incremented ones.

```
V operator++(int dummy)
{
    V v(vec[0],vec[1]);
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        ++vec[i];
    }
    return v;
}
```